# How do I disable random colours for my variables in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, color-scheme

Every time I type in a variable Pycharm makes it a new random colour rather than using a consistent colour for any code that is a variable.

See for yourself:

[image]

I am using Python 2.7 in the code editor.
 I tried playing around with the settings, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: When you press `Ctrl + Shift + A` and type in `Language Defaults." When you select it you should be brought to the settings page `Editor > Color Scheme > Language Defaults`. The bottom half contains samples of types of tokens PyCharm colorizes & line numbers. In the bottom half, scroll up until you see the word "Identifier" (on mine it's line 3) and click it.   

What do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the feature called **Semantic Variable Colours**

You can access it from **Settings -> Editor -> Colors Scheme -> Language defaults**

Or just search in settings like in this image and just uncheck the option for that feature

When its **enabled** looks like this

[image: Semantic Enabled]

To **disable** just uncheck the option like this

[image: Semantic Disabled]

For more Font related stuff visit - [JetBrains PyCharm Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html)

Comment: I tried this, but nothing worked. What am I supposed to do in that setting? I tried unchecking it, I tried changing the colours, nothing worked. Am I missing something? 

edit: nvm, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @ElfMachine Glad It worked. Consider approving and upvoting answer :)

Comment: I did upvote. How do I approve? By the way, how do you disable cursive 'if' statements in the code editor?

Comment: If you want to change code style find it under Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python.

Comment: I tried, but I can't figure out which option it is. I am in the python code style menu, but too many obscure words.

Comment: What you want to achieve meaning to disable cursive if. Can you give example?

Comment: Basically, some of my code shows like this:

_print_ "Hello world!" 

Notice the cursive print? I want to disable that. However, I just used the Darcula standard color scheme and changed it. So, I don't mind anymore. But it would be cool to still know it. Not necessary though. Anyway, thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Glad it worked out with Darcula scheme. Happy to help :)